# How to convert a normalized DenseVector to its unormalized form?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a module named `pyspark.ml.feature` that has a class named `MinMaxScaler`. Its documentation claims:

> Rescale each feature individually to a common range [min, max]
>   linearly using column summary statistics, which is also known as
>   min-max normalization or Rescaling.

Therefore I can use it to normalize my dataset, that is what I did. My problem is when I try to go back to its unormalized form. I have read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=feature#pyspark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler) and can't find anything related to this.

Comment: How would you un-normalize if you lost the information about how it was ? If you don't have the min-max, you can't do it.

Comment: I have the `MinMaxScalerModel` @eliasah